# Flask api on gcloud's URL keeps on loading

Tags: python, api, flask, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I thought that the error was in the code first but, it was in the deployment. So, i deployed my flask api on gcloud after researching a lot. But as I run the URL of my app. It keeps on loading and loading.

i want my api to work properly

Comment: Do you have piece of code?

Comment: Flask code? Yep i have it.

Comment: https://github.com/PersonXXIII/al-siraj-sample-api
here, i uploaded the whole root directory which i deployed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Where are you deploying your code?

Comment: Gcloud using CLI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typographical error. You named your file `requirments.txt` instead of `requirements.txt` i.e. you're missing letter 'e' after letter 'r'. Because of this, your modules/packages aren't installed which means your code won't work (you should see the errors if you check the logs).

**Extra:** Next time, include the specific solution/part of gcloud you're using in your question or the tag(in this case, you're using Google App Engine <s>Standard</s> Flex)

**Updates**

1. You have `app:app` in your `GUNICORN_CMD_ARGS` env variable but your `app` object is in a `main.py` file and not an `app.py` file (you have the correct thing in your `entrypoint` variable.
2. Since you have an `entrypoint`, I don't believe you need the `GUNICORN_CMD_ARGS`. Try the following & see if it resolves your issue - remove `GUNICORN_CMD_ARGS`and update your `entrypoint` to

   `gunicorn -b :$PORT --threads=8 --timeout=7 main:app`

   According to [gunicorn documentation](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#workers), a default value of 1 is used for workers if you don't specify it
3. You should also note that using GAE Flex over GAE standard is more expensive because Flex needs at least 1 instance to always be up whereas Standard can go down to 0 when there's no traffic which in turn means you're paying less. The downside is that it takes sometime to start up an instance when it receives new traffic

Comment: The requirements.txt issue. I solved it already before the deployment. The issue came afterward. So, its not the issue here. (I guess i uploaded the wrong requirements.txt on github). And thanks for the Extra. Its my first time using stack overflow (to ask)

Comment: What does your logs say? Go to console.cloud.google.com, select your project and click on 'Logging' on the left hand side. Then open your app home page again and then check the log

Comment: I just saw that i uploaded the wrong req.txt, main.py and app.yaml on github. sorry for the mistake can you check those files as well and are you talking about these logs: https://imgur.com/a/blvF1Kw

Comment: Its worked. Thanks a lot lot. 
fellow, i have few things i need to know.
01: the link it generated is sometimes too slow sometimes fast to respond. any fix to it.
02: if i change the trained model file along the json files. will and deploy it from the same folder. will it change the env to the application or it will update those files only.
03: will the application deployed shuts down automatically or its dome manuelly. like after a time i try to use the url but will it shut down?

Comment: 1) Usually, when a new instance of an App is started, it takes sometime because it has to run all of your startup code (this is why you're advised to load/import modules only when they're needed rather than at the beginning of the file). You can try to speed things up by using warmup requests - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/java/configuring-warmup-requests    2) The number of instances you have running also affect the response time of the App - the more instances, then the faster the response time but it also means it's costing you more.

Comment: I don't understand your second question. I addressed your third question in my answer (bullet number 3). To expand - GAE is considered serverless and usually, serverless is built to basically go down (think of it as a going to sleep/hibernate) when there's no traffic. However, GAE Flex can shut all other instances down but will always keep at least 1 instance running even when there's no traffic - see the part that talks about 'scaling to zero' on this document - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments#compare_high-level_features

Comment: Like i have a chatbot. Its dataset is still to be improved (its a supervised chatbot). I still have to add dataset then train the model and give it to the api. So that new dataset is also accessible through the api. When i have trained and all and i will deploy the api once again in the same project using the same main.py and the changed files (which will be json files and h5). Will the deployment effect the api which is working right now. Or in other words it will easily be deployed with the changes.